# In WEB API Application While Connect with Excel gives an error I just create a connection with excel and when try to open it's give error

Tags: c#, excel

> oledbConn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException

```cs
case ".xls":
    excelConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
    break;
//If uploaded file is Excel 2007 and above
case ".xlsx":
    //excelConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=filepath;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0; HDR = YES; IMEX = 1";
    excelConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\Users\\AzureUser\\Documents\\Capture.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;HDR =NO'";
    break;
}

docfiles.Add(request);
excelConString = string.Format(excelConString, request);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection excelOledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand excelDbCommand = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            excelDbCommand.Connection = excelOledbConnection;
            //Read Data from First Sheet.
            this.dbClientWrapper.DBOpen(excelOledbConnection);

            excelDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]";
            excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelDbCommand;
            this.dbClientWrapper.CommandReader(excelDbCommand);
            // this.dbClientWrapper.ExecuteQuery(excelDbCommand);
            //Fill datatable from adapter
            DataTable d = this.dbClientWrapper.FillDataTable(excelDataAdapter);
  
            this.dbClientWrapper.DBClose(excelOledbConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is also should be an exception message and maybe even `InnerException` along with `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Is this running in Azure?

Comment: Yes it's running on azure